# Using plistlib to see if key exists

Tags: python

How can I check with plistlib to see if a key value is valid, or whether a key exists?
I tried:

```
if result['Tags'] != "":
    dtags = result["Tags"]
    dotags = '#' + ' #'.join(dtags)
else:
    dotags = ""
```

and it simply returned the error:

```
KeyError: 'Tags'
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to use the `get()` method to check if the key exists:

```
# Here we don't have to compare to anything because a match will return True
if result.get('Tags', None):
    dtags = result["Tags"]
    dotags = '#' + ' #'.join(dtags)
else:
    dotags = ""
```